# Como guardar en una lista los datos de un documento JSON

Tags: javascript, json

Tengo el siguiente JSON, el cual es el resultado puro de una descarga de datos en base de datos:

```
{
"users": {
    "RH5v2EOeUUe9ghYdg95xqPaQmRu2": {
        "creationDate": "22/8/2022 21:01 04",
        "email": "test2@gmail.com",
        "permisson": "user",
        "posts": {
            "22-8-2022 21:01 37": {
                "autor": "test2@gmail.com",
                "contenido": "Soy test2!",
                "fecha": "22/8/2022 21:01 37"
            },
            "22-8-2022 21:09 47": {
                "autor": "test2@gmail.com",
                "contenido": "hooola",
                "fecha": "22/8/2022 21:09 47"
            }
        }
    },
    "SkdaHbKBX3aBeus7achGAi4FEo22": {
        "creationDate": "21/8/2022 16:28",
        "email": "test@gmail.com",
        "permisson": "user",
        "posts": {
            "22-8-2022 19:22 27": {
                "autor": "test@gmail.com",
                "contenido": "prueba",
                "fecha": "22/8/2022 19:22 27"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Necesito guardar todos los posts de cada usuario en una lista para después mostrarlos y no sé como hacerlo, ya que no me está dejando usar map()

Muchas gracias

Comment: `"RH5v2EOeUUe9ghYdg95xqPaQmRu2"` y esto que se supone que es, porque tienes claves dinamicas dentro de tu objeto, porque no mejor una clave estatica para poder acceder mejor cuando lo recorres.

Comment: @David081 es un UUID, cada uno de esos es un usuario distinto. ¿Sería mejor cambiar la forma en la que guardo los datos? ¿Y tener todos los posts agrupados en una única lista?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El metodo `map` no funciona con colecciones que no son iterables, ahi muchas formas de iterar objetos para obtener sus propiedades, aca te muestro una:

```js
let posts = []
let users = {
"users": {
    "RH5v2EOeUUe9ghYdg95xqPaQmRu2": {
        "creationDate": "22/8/2022 21:01 04",
        "email": "test2@gmail.com",
        "permisson": "user",
        "posts": {
            "22-8-2022 21:01 37": {
                "autor": "test2@gmail.com",
                "contenido": "Soy test2!",
                "fecha": "22/8/2022 21:01 37"
            },
            "22-8-2022 21:09 47": {
                "autor": "test2@gmail.com",
                "contenido": "hooola",
                "fecha": "22/8/2022 21:09 47"
            }
        }
    },
    "SkdaHbKBX3aBeus7achGAi4FEo22": {
        "creationDate": "21/8/2022 16:28",
        "email": "test@gmail.com",
        "permisson": "user",
        "posts": {
            "22-8-2022 19:22 27": {
                "autor": "test@gmail.com",
                "contenido": "prueba",
                "fecha": "22/8/2022 19:22 27"
            }
        }
    }
  }
}
//Para la estructura que tienes debes iterar dos veces
for(var item in users){
   //La primera para accerder a users
   for(let item2 in users[item]){
     //La segunda para accerder a los UUID de cada user
     posts.push(users[item][item2].posts)
   }
}
console.log(posts)
```

De esta forma puedes extraer los `post` de cada `user`, esper te sirva.

Te dejo [aca](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) documentacion del `for in` para recorrer objetos
**(Contrario a lo que dije al principio, en este ejemplo, NO es necesario cambiar la clave UUID que mencionas porque asi te va a funcionar)**